# Does a middleware have access to middleware error handler?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am currently using Express and trying to handle a JsonWebToken error gracefully.

I have two middleware functions I have created, one that extracts a user from a jwt token, and one that handles any route errors for specific usecases.

```
const userExtractor = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.token
    if (token) {
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
        const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
        req.user = user
    }

    next()
}
```

If token is included and verified, and finds a user from my database with the id inside the token, a user object is attached to any incoming requests.

I am trying to error handle when someone sends a faulty token. The error occurs with jsonwebtoken `.verify` method.

```
Desktop\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:75
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('invalid token'))
```

My error handle should be handling this specific error, however I am not sure if how middlewares work this is possible.

```
const errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    if (error.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'invalid token has been sent'})
    }
    next(error)
}
```

And yes, I have initiated both middlewares, with the error handler specifically being the last middleware used at the end.

```
// Util middleware
app.use(middleware.tokenExtractor)
app.use(middleware.userExtractor)

// Routes
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api/me', meRouter)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.use(middleware.errorHandler)
```

Comment: [https://github.com/smit-code/node-express-mongoose/](https://github.com/smit-code/node-express-mongoose/) Here a best boilerplate for node mongooose api-requestvalidation and JWT as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle an error in a middleware need to `try catch` section so with return the `next(error)`, middleware error will get the `error` that happened in the middleware

try like the below code

```
const userExtractor = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.token
        if (token) {
            const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
            const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
            req.user = user
        }

        next()
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error);
    }
}
```